# When to use DCAU tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-wiki

DCAU refers to [DC animated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) and should be used for those questions only but here DCAU tag is used for  [DC Universe Animated Original Movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies) too which is wrong. Similar to MCU, DCAU is quite famous term among fans and it have distinct meaning and shouldn't be used with any random DC animated film.

Is it not better to remove it from non DCAU film questions? And submitting a better descriptive tag wiki like movies.se have for the [same tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/dc-animated-universe/info)?

I am also ready for counter argument too.

Comment: correct tags is always a good thing. what should the correct tag be?

Comment: @phantom42 removal of DCAU tag from non DCAU stuff.

Comment: Yes, but what tag should be added?

Comment: @phantom42 We have dc movies tag here. Anyways why do we even need additional tags, for now just with film name tag, will be better then wrong tagging

Comment: The tag wiki specifies multiple universes with separate continuities.  IMHO that's wrong, but it's what the wiki says right now.

Comment: Looks like Ankit’s in the process of fixing things. He edited the tag wikis a little while ago. We’re saved!

Comment: So does this mean that the animated movie by DC don't count in `dcau` o.O

Comment: @ABcDexter Unfortunately yes but there were some canon animated film in DCAU too, refer tag wiki for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to fix as much as I have clear idea about but had doubts with few question, like [this beast boy question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93098/can-beast-boy-turn-into-other-humans), as beast boy never directly appeared in DCAU but had partial cameo in Static shock. Might  also have intentionally/unintentional left few vague ones, which others can help in sorting out.

Anyway Tag wiki for the tag has been fixed to elaborate what is counted as canon. I hope it help future tag users.